# Using custom objects with PrimeNG Chips and Autocomplete

Tags: angular, angular6, primeng

I am attempting to use a combination of `<p-chips>` and `<p-autocomplete>` to display/add/remove custom objects from a list, with the end result being functionally similar to a PickList, but without taking up as much screen estate.

***app.component.ts***

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  val: any;

  targetList = [
    {
      code: '0001',
      name: 'Subject 1'
    },
    {
      code: '0002',
      name: 'Subject 2'
    },
    {
      code: '0003',
      name: 'Subject 3'
    },
  ];

  sourceList = [
    {
      code: '0004',
      name: 'Subject 4'
    },
    {
      code: '0005',
      name: 'Subject 5'
    },
    {
      code: '0006',
      name: 'Subject 6'
    },
  ];

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  addItem(item: any) {
    this.targetList.push(item);
  }
}
```

***app.component.html***

```
Editable chips:
<p-chips [(ngModel)]="targetList" allowDuplicate="false">
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
      {{ item.code }}: {{ item.name }}
  </ng-template>   
</p-chips>

<br>

<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="val" [suggestions]="sourceList" dropdown="true" [minLength]="1" onSelect="addItem($event.value)" [forceSelection]="true" field="code">
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
    {{ item.code }}: {{ item.name }}
  </ng-template>
</p-autoComplete>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<!-- for pages that are read-only -->
Read-only chips:
<p-chips [(ngModel)]="targetList" disabled="true"> 
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">        
    {{ item.code }}: {{ item.name }}       
  </ng-template>          
</p-chips>
```

Following the PrimeNG documentation, I managed to get the `<p-chips>` to work correctly with the custom objects, but I can't get the `<p-autocomplete>` to even display the objects, much less select them for addition to the list. What am I doing wrong here?

[Obligatory stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmpacy)

Comment: <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item"> will not work with [dropdown]="true" you can use [Field] to define the display text